# Have I to count transactions before rollback one in catch block in T-SQL?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, error-handling, transactions

I have next block in the end of each my stored procedure for SQL Server 2008

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN
        -- my code
    COMMIT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF (@@trancount > 0)
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK
        DECLARE @message NVARCHAR(MAX)
        DECLARE @state INT
        SELECT @message = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @state = ERROR_STATE()
        RAISERROR (@message, 11, @state)
    END
END CATCH
```

Is it possible to switch `CATCH`-block to

```
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK
    DECLARE @message NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @state INT
    SELECT @message = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @state = ERROR_STATE()
    RAISERROR (@message, 11, @state)
END CATCH
```

or just

```
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK
END CATCH
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, I never start a new transaction if I'm already in one.

This deals with nested stored procs, distributed TXNs and TransactionScope

Remember, there is [no such thing as a nested transaction in SQL Server](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/) anyway.

```
DECLARE @StartTranCount int

BEGIN TRY
    SET @StartTranCount = @@TRANCOUNT
    IF @StartTranCount = 0 BEGIN TRAN
        -- my code
    IF @StartTranCount = 0 COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @StartTranCount = 0 AND @@trancount > 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRAN
        DECLARE @message NVARCHAR(MAX)
        DECLARE @state INT
        SELECT @message = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @state = ERROR_STATE()
        RAISERROR (@message, 11, @state)
    END
    /*
    or just
    IF @StartTranCount = 0 AND @@trancount  
        ROLLBACK TRAN
    */
END CATCH
```

Comment: I mean that I always start a transaction (and try-block) in the beginning of each my DML stored procedure. So my question is - have I to check @@trancount in appropriate catch-block?

Comment: @abatishchev: yes: it may already have rolled bck (eg in a trigger)

Answer (score 2):

You need to check that there is a transaction in scope before trying to rollback.

You can use the following:

```
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END CATCH;
```

This will rollback the transaction, but no error will be reported back to your application.

Check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx) for more info.

Comment: What if I'm always inside a transaction scope? See my edited post

Comment: If you _know_ that you are within a transaction, then the only statement you will need is the `ROLLBACK` statement. You will still not get any error reported to your app.